# How to display nothing on specific monitors

Tags: windows, graphics-card, display, multiple-monitors, directx

Weird flex but I would like to be able to display purely nothing on Windows 10 on specific screen (with multiple screens configuration). Not just black, but something like as if the screen was shutted off. The closest thing I can think of is when you run a game in fullscreen mode, there is sometimes ( or at least there was at the time I was playing video games) a brief moment when absolutely nothing is displayed, before the game actually run.

So maybe a really short program that would use DirectX to achieve that could do the trick? If any feature is able to do this ? But really any other hacky solution, that would involve a bit of programming, or using a command line tool, is welcomed.

What is not an option :

- Turn Off monitors with MultiMonitor Tool for example (https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/multi_monitor_tool.html) since the screens are wired with HDMI splitters that doesn't supports DDC/CI
- Disabling monitors since it will mess with the program that is broadcasting
- Using a blank screen saver since it just displays black color but the screen is displaying

Thanks !

Comment: What do you mean by "not just black"? Either _something_ is displayed or the display is turned off.

Comment: By "not just black" I mean, not broadcasting a black picture that is taking the whole screen for example. But more like cutting the HDMI broadcasting temporarily. or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows 10, go to

> Advanced Display Settings → Remove display from desktop

section... there's an option to

> Prevent Windows from using this display.
> This display will be available exclusively for special-purpose apps that require it.

Try that and see if it works for you.